# Specialized.StringCollection сохранение и считывание настроек

Tags: c#, properties, настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется ListBox фильтра вложений. Для сохранения настроек используется данный код:

```
                Properties.Settings.Default["Path"] = tbPath.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default["SiteName"] = cbxSite.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default["MailAdress"] = tbMail.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default["MailPassword"] = tbMailPassword.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default["Latency"] = Convert.ToInt32(cbxLatency.Text);
                Properties.Settings.Default["DeleteMails"] = cbDelete.Checked;
```

Вопрос такой, использую для фильтра System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection в настройках, но не могу понять как сохранить их.

Для выгрузки данных с настроек использую данный код:

```
            tbPath.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["Path"].ToString();
            cbxSite.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["SiteName"].ToString();
            tbMail.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["MailAdress"].ToString();
            tbMailPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["MailPassword"].ToString();
            cbxLatency.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["Latency"].ToString();
            cbDelete.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Properties.Settings.Default["DeleteMails"]);
```

И опять-таки не могу понять как выгружать тип данных StringCollection.

Comment: А почему вы обращаетесь по ключу, а не с использованием свойств? Вместо `Properties.Settings.Default["Path"]` используйте `Properties.Settings.Default.Path`. Строгая типизация — наше всё. А вообще почитайте про приведение типов: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась парочкой циклов `foreach`

Оставляю код тем кому может пригодится:

Заполнение данных:

```
foreach (string item in lbFilter.Items)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Filter.Add(item);
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Выгрузка данных:

```
foreach(string s in Properties.Settings.Default.Filter)
        {
            if (!lbFilter.Items.Contains(s))
            {
                lbFilter.Items.Add(s);
            }

        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Filter.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Для примера возьмем такой набор контролов
[image: пример интерфейса программы]

Создадим для них соответствующие переменные. Обратите внимание на типы переменных.
[image: переменные для сохранения настроек]

Тогда читать и сохранять настройки можно так

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _textBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textBox;
        _checkBox.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox;
        _comboBox.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.comboBox;

        List<bool> values = Properties.Settings.Default.checkedList.OfType<string>()
                                                                     .Select(s => s.Equals("1") ? true : false)
                                                                     .ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < _checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            _checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, values[i]);
        }
    }

    private void _buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.textBox = _textBox.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox = _checkBox.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.comboBox = _comboBox.SelectedIndex;

        for (int i = 0; i < _checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.checkedList[i] = 
                _checkedListBox.GetItemChecked(i) ? "1" : "0";
        }

        //сохраняем настройки
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```