# Как сделать чтобы последние введенные данные в textbox запомнились и были при следующем открытии? C#

Tags: c#, form, textbox

У меня есть форма для фильтрации данных перед заходом в БД, можно ли сделать так, чтобы программа запоминала(сохраняла) какие данные были введены крайний раз и при следующем открытии формы они были сразу в textbox? Код работы формы ниже

[image: Форма]

```
public override SqlCmdText GetSqlFilter()
    {
        var Cond = ITnet2.Server.Dialogs.InputForm.Activate("_TESTFRM");
        if (Cond.Success)
        {
            string Conditions = "";
            // условие по дате C
            var date_d = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<DateTime>("DATE_D");
            if (date_d != null)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " cast(PWREG.DATE_D as date) >= cast(@date_d as date) ";
            }
            // условие по дате ПО
            var date_to = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<DateTime>("END");
            if (date_to != null)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and cast(PWREG.DATE_D as date) <= cast(@date_to as date) ";
            }
            var n_kdk = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<string>("N_KDK");
            var rcentr = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<string>("RCENTR");
            var ceh = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<string>("CEH");
            // условие по сотруднику
            if (n_kdk != null && n_kdk.Length > 0)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and PWREG.N_KDK = @n_kdk ";
            }
            // условие по рабочему центру
            if (rcentr != null && rcentr.Length > 0)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and PWREG.RCENTR = @rcentr ";
            }
            // условие по цеху
            if (ceh != null && ceh.Length > 0)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and PRCR.CEH = @ceh ";
            }
            return new SqlCmdText(string.Format(Conditions),
                new SqlParam("n_kdk", n_kdk.ToString()),
                new SqlParam("rcentr", rcentr.ToString()),
                new SqlParam("ceh", ceh.ToString()),
                new SqlParam("date_d", date_d),
                new SqlParam("date_to", date_to));
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852535/222542

Comment: @Bulson плюса не хватало? :)

Comment: @Bulson правильно ли я понимаю, что там указано как сохранить данные в памяти? я не силен в этом, к сожалению)

Comment: и как это все реализовать в моем коде?)

Comment: @aepot спасибо за оценку 

Comment: Данные сохраняются в xml конфиг. файл вашей программы. В примере показано, что при загрузке формы данные можно прочитать, а по нажатию на кнопку сохранить. Вам осталось прикрутить часть этого кода к своему случаю. Пользователь ввел дату - вы сохраняете эти значения, когда форма загружается вы считываете сохраненные данные в текстбокс.